# Eclipse -> Java -> accessing controls from functions

Tags: java, eclipse

Newbie, so be kind.

Using eclipse for Java EE, added a WindowsBuilder Application Form.
Added some controls. Then created in the same java file as the ui a function, at the bottom, called ResetUI() that I made public.

In NetBeans, I can access from that functions my controls, you know, simply empty the textboxes etc.

In Eclipse, I can't. 
For example: 
     jftSourceWidth.setText("");

will show the lightbulb saying "jftSourceWidth cannot be resolved".

Why, oh why???

I mean, its all in the same source, the same works in NetBeans. 
How do I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse WindowBuilder elements are local variables by default, and as such, cannot be accessed by `main` or any scopes that are not the function initializing the window. You need to use the "convert to field" feature of WindowBuilder:

[image]

It should now be accessible in all non-static scopes of your window class.

Comment: @InnerOrchestra Thanks, if you find that this answer has helped you satisfactorily, please click the gray checkmark to the left of it to mark it as resolving your question.

Comment: Will do in 6 minutes( popup) Hey doesn't this seems tedious when you have a lot of controls to work with? Is there a setting in the preference or somewhere? Mm..

Comment: @InnerOrchestra I'm not entirely sure, but it may be possible to select all intended elements and convert them. I would only do this for elements that *need* this, due to code- and debugging-bloat that may be possible.